# Executing ruby code without saving a file

Tags: ruby, string, exec

I am wondering how can I execute ruby code without saving a file. For example:

```
ruby -e 'Time.now'
```

However, the quotes are a problem, for example:

```
ruby -e 'puts 'A syntax error''
```

I could use doble quotes instead:

```
ruby -e 'puts "No error"'
```

Or:

```
ruby -e "puts 'No error'"
```

The issue is that I am running arbitrary code inside a container so I can't avoid the issue with a manual replacement and scaping the quotes also generates an error:

```
ruby -e 'puts \'A syntax error\''
```

So I wonder how can I execute ruby code without files and without worrying about quotes inside the code.

Comment: How about a heredoc?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of what "I am running arbitrary code inside a container" actually means. Where is this arbitrary code coming from? and What process are you going through to execute it?

Comment: In future please consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. Quick selections can discourage other answers (pardon the sloppy grammar) and can be a bummer to those still working on answers. There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours, some wait longer, encouraging then-sleeping members an opportunity to contribute.

Comment: @red, good suggestion.

Comment: Oh, sorry, @CarySwoveland, I thought selecting an answer was related to the solution of my particular problem. I will consider next time, thanks!

Comment: @engineersmnky I am testing literate programming writen on pads. Since Ruby is the lang I feel more confortable, I am implementing the prototipe on that lang. The prototipe selects the ruby blocks, put them together and execute them. For security reasons everything is done inside a disposaval container (a GitLab pipeline). So, with “arbitrary code” I mean that it could be any Ruby code, no restrictions. I didn't want to save it in a file since I consider it is not neccesary and I didn't want to touch the code, like scaping quotes, since it could turn very messy.

Comment: Ouch. Be very careful with that, just because something is "inside a container" does not mean it cannot reach outside the container and "it could be any Ruby code, no restrictions" means system level manipulation is very doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Shell HEREDOC. *<s>The exact syntax may differ between shells but in BASH it is</s>*:
**Edit**: *All Shells have the same syntax and behave the same way (see IEEE standard quote below).*

```sh
ruby <<'EOS'
$error = 'A syntax error'
puts $error
EOS
```

***Note**: The quotes of `<<'EOS'` prevent the Shell from expanding variables inside the HEREDOC, or else `$error` would be expanded before being passed to Ruby. Also, you can use whatever **word** you prefer instead of `EOS`, for ex:*

```sh
ruby <<'end of ruby script'
puts 'example'
end of ruby script
```

---

**The IEEE standard says:**

> 2.7.4 **Here-Document**
>
> The redirection operators `<<` and `<<-` both allow redirection of lines contained in a shell input file, known as a "here-document", to the input of a command.
>
> The here-document shall be treated as a single word that begins after
> the next `<newline>` and continues until there is a line containing only
> the delimiter and a `<newline>`, with no `<blank>`s in between. Then the
> next here-document starts, if there is one. The format is as follows:
>
> ```
> [n]<<word  
>     here-document  
> delimiter
> ```
>
> where the optional n represents the file descriptor number. If the number is omitted, the here-document refers
> to standard input (file descriptor 0).
>
> **If any character in word is quoted**, the delimiter shall be formed by
> performing quote removal on word, and **the here-document lines shall
> not be expanded**. Otherwise, the delimiter shall be the word itself.
>
> If no characters in word are quoted, all lines of the here-document
> shall be expanded for parameter expansion, command substitution, and
> arithmetic expansion. In this case, the backslash in the input behaves
> as the backslash inside double-quotes (see Double-Quotes). However,
> the double-quote character ( `'"'` ) shall not be treated specially
> within a here-document, except when the double-quote appears within
> `$()`, ``` `` ```, or `${}`.
>
> If the redirection symbol is `<<-`, all leading `<tab>`s shall be
> stripped from input lines and the line containing the trailing
> delimiter

---

### Update

That said, it's impossible to completely prevent conflicts. For example this Ruby code would break your Shell script:

```sh
ruby <<'EOS'
puts <<-EOS
example
EOS
EOS
```

The only way to work around that is to use a **word** that is very unlikely to appear in the Ruby code, for example:

```sh
ruby <<'2eGRng8B6NEmNphkA2K4yc9Y782PQZpWzkUW7pwGdmybuMBG5 PVtkzZkeSKGLq4'
puts <<-EOS
example
EOS
2eGRng8B6NEmNphkA2K4yc9Y782PQZpWzkUW7pwGdmybuMBG5 PVtkzZkeSKGLq4
```

Comment: @red-menace, now I understand your suggestion. Nice answer, Fravadona, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the quotes properly, for example:

```
ruby -e 'puts '\''foo bar'\''; puts '\''foo bar'\''; '
#       ^-----^
#      quote this
#                ^-------^
#                quote that
#              ^^
#      escaped quote to pass to Ruby
```

Output:

```
foo bar
foo bar
```

Note that most quotes are needed to simply quote the Ruby code in the shell. The escaped quote `\'` is an actual quote that is passed to Ruby.

Comment: Can you explain why `'` becomes `'\''`?

Comment: @Stefan, thank you for the comment, updated the answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Ruby's [String Literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings)

To avoid (or at least simplify) the issue of quoting String objects inside shell quotes, you can use a [heredoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents+-28heredocs-29) or a [percent-string](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) such as `%q` for single quotes or `%Q` for double-quotes. For example:

```
# double-quoted percent string
ruby -e 'puts %Q(No error.)'

# single-quoted percent string
ruby -e 'puts %q(A syntax error.)'

# quoted String with nested symbols
ruby -e 'puts %Q[You can use most [percent-literal] symbols safely.]'
```

Note that you can use almost any paired or unnpaired symbol character to open and close the percent literal. `()`, `[]`, and `{}` are common choices, but anything other than single quotes and `\'` should be safe from the shell inside a single-quoted argument to `-e`.